# Определение самого контрастного цвета для заданного кадра

Tags: c++, opencv

Вобщем вопрос состоит в том как найти самый контрастный цвет для данного кадра. Допусим мы уже получили усредненную палитру цведов для кадра, как найти цвет который не сольётся с этой палитрой?